# Does mutliple functions in GROUP BY like concat or cast or dateformat affect the query time?

Tags: mysql, function, group-by, query-optimization

I have a query which is taking more time to execute . I am trying to optimize it. There are functions in the GROUP BY which may be adding to the query time . So i am trying to figure out how to optimize that part.

I am using Mysql 5.5.17 .

I cannot use force index as i am using Hibernate, so that's out of option .

I have some other options like :

1) use the alias in place of concat(...) in group by.

2) or replace concat() with the the columns inside it .

Ex: group by concat(1,2,3.) => group by 1,2,3

After trying both the above options i dont see any difference in "Query Cost"

The query looks like this(table names changed) :

```
    select  sum(this_.a + this_.b + this_.c + this_.d + this_.e +
                this_.f + this_.g + this_.h + this_.i + this_.j) as sent,
        sum(this_.a + this_.b + this_.c + this_.d + this_.e) as delivered,
        d2_.name as y2_, d2_.id as y3_, concat(cast(b4_.id as char),
               '.',c1_.name,'.',cs5_.name,'_',date_format(b4_.createddate,
                       '%Y-%b-%d %H:%i:%s')
                          ) as allias_concat, b4_.id as y5_,
        this_.year as y6_, this_.month as y7_, this_.day as y8_,
        this_.weekday as y9_, this_.weekofmonth as y10_,
        this_.bltid as y11_,
        b4_.id as y12_, c1_.name as y13_,
        cs5_.name as y14_, b4_.createddate as y15_,
        cs5_.subject as y16_, d2_.name as y17_
    from  TABLE1 this_
    inner join  TABLE2 c1_   on this_.cgnid=c1_.id
    inner join  TABLE3 b4_   on this_.bltid=b4_.id
    inner join  TABLE4 csc6_ on b4_.schdlid=csc6_.id
    inner join  TABLE5 cs5_  on this_.constid=cs5_.id
    left outer join  TABLE6 f3_ on this_.fid=f3_.id
    inner join  TABLE7 d2_ on this_.dptid=d2_.id
    where  (f3_.name<>'TRASH'
              or  c1_.fid=0
           )
      and  c1_.status<>'K'
      and  d2_.id in (1)
      and  ((b4_.createddate between '2015-02-01 10:30:00'
                                 AND '2015-05-13 10:29:59'
                      and  csc6_.isrealtime = 'N'
                          )
              or  (csc6_.isrealtime = 'Y'
                      and  this_.bltdate between '2015-02-01 10:30:00'
                                             AND '2015-05-13 10:29:59')
           )
    group by  d2_.id,
              concat(cast(b4_.id as char),'.',c1_.name,'.',cs5_.name,'_',
                     date_format(b4_.createddate,'%Y-%b-%d %H:%i:%s')
                    ),
              b4_.id,
              this_.year, this_.month, this_.day,
              this_.bltid
    limit  20001
```

Please suggest ...

Thanks In Advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is going to be an "anti-answer"...

It smells like "over-normalization".  For example, it feels like `b4_` is a normalization of a datetime (`createddate`) and nothing else.  Is this correct?  If so, that is adding complexity and slowing down both the `WHERE` and the `GROUP BY`, plus obliterating some optimization possibilities.

The "functions" are not the problem.  Since the items in the `GROUP BY` are coming from different tables, there is *no* way to optimize it.  The `GROUP BY` must gather the information from the various tables, put them in a temp table, sort it, then scan through it.  (Or something like that.  The point is that there is no shortcut.)

"I cannot use ... as i am using Hibernate" -- Yet another case where a 3rd party software "gets in the way".  If you can't change the query, we can't help you.

Comment: How about i replace the **concat** function from the **GROUP BY** with the columns used in the fuction in a comma separated manner.

Comment: Since the items in the GROUP BY are coming from different tables, there is no way to optimize it.  Replacing the `concat` may have a miniscule impact.